# Cannot perform NuGet pack

Tags: wcf, nuget, pack

I get the following error when trying to perform a NuGet pack.

> The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WCF\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. 
>   C:\Projects\MyProject.csproj

I am trying to perform the pack in my PostBuild event with the following command:

> nuget pack "C:\Projects\MyProject.csproj" -Properties
>   Configuration=Release -IncludeReferencedProjects -OutputDirectory
>   ..\..\

I also tried to perform the pack from the command line and got the same error.

I am using NuGet 2.5.XXX.  I am using Visual Studio 2015 SP3.  My project is a WCF Service Library.  I use the Post Build command in many other projects with no problem.  Also, I have created other WCF services with no problem.

I suppose I should upgrade NuGet, but am slightly afraid it may break something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade the nuget. That will upgrade all the references that you were using that will not break any of your functionalities.